# If $f_1$ and $f_2$ are two polynomials are not divisible by polynomial g. is it possible that the sum $f_1 +f_2$ is divisible by g.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

If $f_1$ and $f_2$ are two polynomials are not divisible by polynomial g. is it possible that the sum $f_1 +f_2$ is divisible by g.

My approach :

I have considered the polynomials like $f_1 = x^2-3x+2 = (x-2)(x-1)$

and $f_2 = (x-4)(x-5)$

and $g(x) = (x-2)(x-5)$

Sum of $f_1 +f_2 = x^2-3x+ 2 +x^2 -9x +20 = 2x^2 -12x +22 $ this is not divisible by g(x)

Can you please guide me more on this concept.. will be of great help thanks..

Comment: Find a case where $f_1+f_2=g.$

Comment: Other have already given examples. This is the same as natural numbers. Think about $5$ and $4$, neither of them are divisible by $3$ but $5+4=9$ is divisible by $3$.

Comment: Well if you take $f_1=-f_2$ then their sum is divisible by any polynomial

Answer (score 2):

Sure. Let $f_1=x-1$, $f_2=1$, $g=x$. Then $x|1+(x-1)$.

The general idea is to just take any random thing for $f_1$ and $g$, choose any multiple of $g$, and subtract $f_1$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume 4 new polynomials represented by $q_1, q_2, r_1$ and $r_2$ so as
$$f_1 = (q_1)g + r_1 \\
f_2 = (q_2)g + r_2$$

The polynomials are in such a way that degree of $r_1$ and $r_2$ are less than that of $g$.

Now, $$f_1 + f_2 = (q_1 + q_2)g + (r_1 + r_2)$$

The only way for $f_1 + f_2$ to be a divisible by $g$ is that $r_1 + r_2$ become $0$ themselves.

But if you choose $r_1$ and $r_2$ in such a way that their degrees can be equal to or greater than that of $g$, then for $f_1 + f_2$ to be a divisible by $g$ is that $r_1 + r_2$ shall become divisible by $g$ as well.

Hope it helps.